# how to upload video with GET through http in PHP?

Tags: php

hello i was wondering what is the best way to upload a video to a website? should I do it through a page with GET and if so how is the file uploaded through http? i am a little confused as to how this would work? I am trying to upload files from iphone and android devices so i cannot use a form to do this, at least i don't think so is there a way to upload my file through http? or what is the most convenient way? thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most pressing issue here is that the HTTP specification requires that `GET` requests be both **safe** and **idempotent**. Uploading video will likely be neither of these.

[Section *9.1.1 Safe Methods* in RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1):

> In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and
>   HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action
>   other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe".
>   This allows user agents to represent other methods, such as POST, PUT
>   and DELETE, in a special way, so that the user is made aware of the
>   fact that a possibly unsafe action is being requested.

So no, bandwidth has nothing to do with it. HTTP itself says you shouldn't be uploading any sort of file by way of the `GET` method.

Comment: +1 Nice. Links to standards are always good :-) And it is explained, too.

Answer (score 6):

GET does not allow for enough bandwidth for a video. Use POST or PUT instead.

Comment: thank you! and to upload without a form let's say a device should i still use a query after the url like  "?name= some value"

Comment: That is completely dependent on how the code on the server expects it.

Comment: what do you mean? i am only trying to upload video lets say every 30 seconds. can php long poll for videos like this or will it behave like an event, like every time i upload something new i will have to delete the older files. this is for a livestream personal project i am trying to make. thank you +1 on your answer.

Comment: That is completely dependent on how the server handles it.

Comment: True, `POST` or `PUT` should be used, but it depends on the video. Short videos can be uploaded using `GET`.

Comment: @Shaquin: If by "short" you mean 2kB or less, then sure. Anything larger is likely to hit a limit either in the web server or in a security system in front of it, and will probably piss off the sysadmin in either case.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams - Yeah, that's what I meant.

Comment: Most videos have *headers* larger than 2kB, so... I hope you like your blinking pixel.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that *anyone* use `GET` for videos. `GET` is for GETting data, and `POST` is for POSTing data. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[The official standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3) (RFC 2616) states

> The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an entity) is identified by the Request-URI.

So, uploading a video would not come under 'retrieving information'.

`POST` should be used, like this:

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
```